# Two way binding not working in checkbox when using directive

Tags: angularjs, checkbox

I have created a directive, which provide data to checkbox according to which checkbox is created. 
and there is another mainList which have an array how many times same checkbox need to be created. 
While putting under ng-repeat of mainList two way binding stops working

```
Attached is the link to fiddle   
 http://jsfiddle.net/mayurdoshi5/t7kr8/1238/
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this is what you are looking for: http://jsfiddle.net/t7kr8/1239/

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.isChecked" />

        {
            "id": 3,
            "isChecked": false,
            "value": "orange",
        }
```

You need to add one more parameter for json array to have the status check

Comment: Thanks @Mithun, It is not working as desired, On selection of apple all apple should be selected same applies to all.

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/rgKUsYGDo9O3tewL6xgr?p=preview might help you to understand better about directives

Comment: I want solution for checkbox for select it is working fine